# Pass value into {{ form.Product_ID }} in HTML Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i use the

```
{{ form.Product_PId }}
```

to make this field

is there anyway to pass this value

```
{{ Product.PId }}
```

where the PId is a primary key from another database

and be like this

```
<input id="id_Product_ID" min="0" name="Product_ID" type="number" value="{{Product.PId}}" required="">
```

so that the end result would be like

```
<input id="id_Product_ID" min="0" name="Product_ID" type="number" value="1" required="">
```

**to sum up the question

is there a way to pass {{ Product.PId }} into {{ form.Product_PId }}
so that the {{ Product.PId }} value could turn into usable number taken from another database**

reference

forms.py

```
class PlaceOrder(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ["Product_ID","HowMany","DateSubmit",]
```

HTML

```
{% for Product in Display_Product %}
        <form method="post" action="" id="CartInput"> {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                {{ form.Product_ID }}
                {{ form.HowMany }}
                {{ form.DateSubmit }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input name="Cart{{ Product.PId }}" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
            </div>
        </form>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class Catalogue(generic.ListView, ModelFormMixin):
    template_name = 'Shop/Catalogue.html'
    model = models.Order
    form_class = forms.PlaceOrder

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Display_Product = Product.objects.all()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        *** tried this one but failed, it just pass in the string {{Product.PId}} and not turn into number ***
        form = PlaceOrder(initial= {'Product_ID': "{{Product.PId}}"})
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'date': now,
            'Display_Product': Display_Product
        }
        return render(request, 'Shop/Catalogue.html', context)
```

thanks and sorry for the long question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the {{ }} syntax to reference an object is only used in templates. 
On your view you should just use Object.id when passing your initial values.

```
...
# Get the object that you need
product = Product.objects.first()
# Define your initial values
form = PlaceOrder(initial= {'Product_ID':  product.id })
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer will try that later, when i get back to my comp  i will wait for a few more answers before i choose as correct answer :

Answer (score 0):

this is what i was looking for , found out that i can use different form method and combine them

i will put it out here hope someone might find it useful

```
<form method="post" action="" id="CartInput"> {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <input name="Product_ID" type="hidden" value="{{ Product.PId }}" >
                <input name="HowMany" type="number" value="1" >
                {{ form.DateSubmit }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input name="Cart{{ Product.PId }}" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
            </div>
        </form>
```